# MarshallComponentException: ('Could not convert component args to JSON', ValueError('Circular reference detected')) Langchain and cognitive search

Tags: python, streamlit

I am testing LangChain with Azure Cognitive Search Retriever:
https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/indexes/retrievers/examples/azure_cognitive_search.html

But I am using streamlit chat component and I get this error:

```
MarshallComponentException: ('Could not convert component args to JSON', ValueError('Circular reference detected'))
```

Basically I get the results from Cogntive Search and With OpenAI and Langchain I should get answers in plain english, however cognitive search results are returned in json format.

COde is below:

```
def get_text():
    input_text = st.text_input("You: ","Periwinkle", key="input")
    return input_text 

def query(payload, docs, chain):   
    response = chain({"query": payload})
    thisdict = {
        "generated_text": response
    }
    return thisdict

def main():
    st.title('Scenario 2: Question Aswering on documents with langchain, pinecone and openai')
    st.markdown(
        """
        This scenario shows how to chat wih a txt file which was indexed in pinecone.
        """
    )

    pinecone.init(
        api_key=PINECONE_API_KEY,  # find at app.pinecone.io
        environment=PINECONE_ENV  # next to api key in console
    )
        
    if 'generated' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state['generated'] = []

    if 'past' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state['past'] = []

 
    embed = OpenAIEmbeddings(deployment=OPENAI_EMBEDDING_DEPLOYMENT_NAME, model=OPENAI_EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME, chunk_size=1)
    user_input = get_text()
   
    retriever = AzureCognitiveSearchRetriever(content_key="FirstName")
    docs =retriever.get_relevant_documents(user_input)
    
    llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
        openai_api_base=OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_ENDPOINT,
        openai_api_version=OPENAI_API_VERSION ,
        deployment_name=OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
        openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY,
        openai_api_type = OPENAI_API_TYPE ,
        model_name=OPENAI_MODEL_NAME,
        temperature=0)
    
    chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
        llm=llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=retriever, return_source_documents=True)

    if user_input:
        output = query({
            "inputs": {
                "past_user_inputs": st.session_state.past,
                "generated_responses": st.session_state.generated,
                "text": user_input,
            },"parameters": {"repetition_penalty": 1.33}
        },
        docs=docs,
        chain=chain)
        
        st.session_state.past.append(user_input)
        st.session_state.generated.append(output["generated_text"])
        
    
    if st.session_state['generated']:
        for i in range(len(st.session_state['generated'])-1, -1, -1):
            message(st.session_state["generated"][i], key=str(i))
            message(st.session_state['past'][i], is_user=True, key=str(i) + '_user')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and the error is thrown here:

```
message(st.session_state["generated"][i], key=str(i))
```